# Prevent a function to be triggered more than once

Tags: jquery

I am trying to prevent a function to run more than once when conditions are fulfilled

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (scrollvalue === wHeight) {
        function()
    }
});
```

I want the whole thing to run only the very first time and then being ignored or just not run anymore even if conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: what are the conditions?

Comment: Prevent execution of which function? You can unbind event listener with `$(window).off('scroll');`. Internal function can be executed or not executed using `if`.

Comment: var scrollValue=$(window).scrollTop();var wHeight = $(window).height();. That scroll value is equal to the window height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i just want the whole thing to run only the very first time

Use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$(window).one('scroll', function(){
});
```

> or just not run anymore even if conditions are fulfilled

Use [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if (condition){
        $(this).off('scroll');
    }
});
```

Comment: _As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements_

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable:

```
var conditionsSet = false;
```

Then, once the conditions are met, set it to true:

```
conditionsSet = true;
```

Then, in the if statement, add that as a condition:

```
if(blah ... && conditionsSet == true)
{}
```

Comment: `&& conditionsSet == true` can simple be `&& conditionsSet`

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use basic javascript function means check the condition flag inside the function. And false that condition end of the function.
2. If you want to use the jquery events on html element use .one function.

   ```
   $( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
       alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
   });
   ```